# AutoHotkey: Remap shortcut for MS Visio to align manually selected objects to the top (as if pressing: "AlignTop")

Tags: c#, c++, vba, autohotkey, visio

I am trying to remap pressing the NumpadUp button to align to the top any number of objects in Microsoft Visio (C#), that I have previously selected. For this, I am using a AutoHotkey script (C++).

I cannot figure out how to specify the parameters of the "visVertAlignTop" function.

Below a version of the code that I have already tried.

I tried searching for some answers on the official Microsoft docs page, but it's all written for C# and not C++, and I can't figure out how to rewrite it in C++, so that it works on the AutoHotkey program.

In Example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-add-shapes-to-a-visio-document?view=vs-2019

```
NumpadUp::

Visio.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Align.visVertAlignTop

return
```

Comment: What are the parameters of the "visVertAlignTop" function?

Comment: In the doc you'll find out that both the horizontal and the vertical alignment are required arguments: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/visio.selection.align

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could use NumpadUp to send the key combination that activates the command in the ribbon. I do that in PowerPoint to align shapes in the middle. 
I don't currently have Visio, so I'm not sure about the exact keys to send.

You'll need to send Alt (!), activate the right ribbon tab (probably Home, h), and then the keystrokes to activate the objects to the top. After you press the alt key, Visio should display little bubbles to tell you which key to press.

Your code should look something like this:

```
NumpadUp::

Send, !h

return
```